# Want to convert the jquery code to pure JavaScript or AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My Project has no dependency of `jquery`, so I want to convert the `jquery` code to pure `angular js` or `javascript`, this is the main which i need to convert is

```
var container = $('.dynamic-content');
container.html('<div ng-controller="TempCtrl"> <h2>About</h2> <h3>{{total}}</h3> <p>Testing the total</p> <button ng-click="update()">Update</button> </div> <script> console.log("begin"); console.log(app.controller); app.controller("TempCtrl", function ($scope) { $scope.total = 0; console.log("inside"); $scope.update = function () { $scope.total = $scope.total + 1; }; }); console.log("end") <\/script>');                  
var newScope = angular.element(container).scope();
var compile = angular.element(container).injector().get('$compile');
compile($(container).contents())(newScope);
```

and this is my plunker
[Pure Angularjs](https://plnkr.co/edit/EAa9Md36hDzpQ1BgIQKg?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

for what i see you need to use `document.queryselector` this method will do the trick of selecting the element

if you want to seek for more expression of `jQuery`to `native javascript` you can check [this site](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why you have this mixed code base. But here it is: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pbwHm6ugQRQ8fcQPVswM?p=preview).

Use `ng-show` to show/hide the dynamic content:

```
<div class="dynamic-content" ng-show="loaded">
  <h2>About</h2>
  <h3>{{total}}</h3>
  <p>Testing the total</p>
  <button ng-click="update()">Update</button>
</div>
```

Also do not need the `TempCtrl`, just move the method `update()` to the controller `AppCtrl`.

=============

Upon request, rewrote it to use directive instead ([Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pbwHm6ugQRQ8fcQPVswM?p=preview)). The directive is like:

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      template: '<div><h2>About</h2><h3>{{total}}</h3><p>Testing the total</p><button ng-click="update()">Update</button></div>',
      controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.total = 0;
        $scope.update = function() {
          $scope.total += 1;
        };
      }]
    };
  });
```

Use it like:

```
<div class="dynamic-content" ng-if="loaded">
  <div my-directive></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But i get the `html` in string along with `script` tags

Comment: Then you need a directive. If you want to reuse this piece of HTML somewhere else, you can use it.

Comment: yes i even did that but angularjs code is not working while doing this....here is my plunker https://jsfiddle.net/fLa9o1pe/9/

Comment: yes i saw it, but i even get the `controller creation` inside of script tag, but your just loading the html i even trying to do this with script tags in which i have contoller creation

Comment: Yes, this is the "pure AngularJS" way.

Comment: Yes this is pure angualrjs i agree, but in my string i am having a html tags along with script tags, and in script tags i am creating a controller, and i even wrote `ng-click` function but not working https://jsfiddle.net/fLa9o1pe/9/

Comment: If you want to create a controller on the fly, try [`angulrAMD`](https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD). I do not think including a controller using `<script></script>` is a good way.

Comment: yes i know its the requirement, and i have seen this `angualrAMD` but did't get to know from where to start

Comment: I am afraid that your `ng-controller` is not interpreted by Angular if you load it in the `<script></script>`. Because Angular finishes the bootstrapping already. Anyway, it is not `Angular` way. If your requirement is like that, sorry that I cannot help.